# Border background on CS spritesheet selection

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to add a border to a transparent spritesheet?

Let's say I have this:

```css
.sq {
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/2/1/e2a2c021dba58c1a7c98252d3b1a6568-full.png);
  height: 32px;
  background-position: left -160px top -32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sq"></div>
```

How would I make it so I could add a small 2px yellow border on its transparent edge? I know I can make it sepia or hue/saturation... but I haven't found a way for border on a spritesheet.

I want a border on the IMAGE itself. Not the DIV or container.

Comment: Do you want to add border to `<div>` or to the image itself? If you need border around `div` just use `.sq{border:2px yellow solid}`.

Comment: @JakubMuda I want to add a border around to the image itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add filter : drop-shadow in your class 
  `filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 0 yellow) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 yellow);` it will works

```css
.sq {
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/2/1/e2a2c021dba58c1a7c98252d3b1a6568-full.png);
  height: 32px;
  background-position: left -160px top -32px;
  width: 32px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 0 yellow)
                  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 yellow);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 0 yellow) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="sq"></div>
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I want a border around the actual image.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Do you need to add `-webkit-filter` as well? Is it still necessary in 2019?

Comment: If you are using safari browser then you can use `-webkit-filter` other wise you don't need... from 2019 have to check

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I forgot about that property. Thank you!